# ContactsContract - Which contacts should I display? (Visible groups)

Tags: android, visible, contactscontract

I need to create a List with all phone numbers found on the device. So what I did, was query the `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`as follows:

```
            Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { Data.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP,// 0
            Data.DISPLAY_NAME, // 1
            Phone.NUMBER, // 2
            Phone.TYPE, // 3
            Phone.LABEL, // 4
    };
    String SELECTION = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            + "' AND " + Data.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = 1";
    String[] SELECTARGS = null;
    String SORTORDER = null;
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, PROJECTION, SELECTION,
            SELECTARGS, SORTORDER);
```

When I run the code on my Nexus 4, no matter the display options I set in the People app (the default Contact Manager), the cursor is always filled with the same contacts. Shouldn't the Data.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP's value be changed according to that setting? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Visiting documentation [`ContactsContract.Data`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) variable IN_VISIBLE_GROUP

> int     IN_VISIBLE_GROUP     read-only     See ContactsContract.Contacts.

Following the [`ContactsContract.Contacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) and finding `IN_VISIBLE_GROUP` explained as:

> An indicator of whether this contact is supposed to be visible in the
>   UI. "1" if the contact has at least one raw contact that belongs to a
>   visible group; "0" otherwise.

So it seems that `Data.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP` has noting to do with the People app visibility status.

---

On the other hand when you click it you moved [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#IN_VISIBLE_GROUP) where is mentioned:

> Flag that reflects the [GROUP_VISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.GroupsColumns.html#GROUP_VISIBLE) state of any
>   [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.html) for this contact.
>   Constant Value: "in_visible_group"

Where `GROUP_VISIBLE` refers to:

> Flag indicating if the contacts belonging to this group should be
>   visible in any user interface.
>
> Type: INTEGER (boolean) Constant Value: "group_visible"

taking into consideration the last 2 quotes it should function as you expected!

Comment: Isn't IN_VISIBLE_GROUP a reflection of GROUP_VISIBLE?